# Как сделать чтобы одновременно работал height: 100vh; background-size: cover;?

Tags: html, css

```css
.home {
  background-image: url("https://s1.1zoom.ru/big3/803/374490-svetik.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
</section>
```

Comment: При уменьшение экрана не включается  код (background-size: cover;)

Comment: Они отлично работают вместе. Возможно нужен более наглядный пример, чтобы разобраться в данной проблеме.

Comment: При уменьшение экрана background не уменьшается и за того что стоит height: 100vh; Если бы было-бы не height: 100vh; то при уменьшение background уменьшался Но мне надо чтобы работало и height: 100vh; и background-size: cover; Для фона ЧТобы при уменьшение экрана уменьшались все изображения .

Comment: Давайте зайдем с другой стороны. Что вы имеете ввиду под "уменьшением экрана"? Вы уменьшаете ширину или высоту? или и все вместе? какой результат вы получаете? Скриншот можете показать?

Comment: Я уменьшаю ширину

Comment: background-size: cover; помещает изображение на 100% по одной из сторон. Если вам нужно чтобы изображение вмещалось полностью, то нужно использовать background-size: contain;